# Question about a property of lattice-morphism

Tags: lattice-orders, universal-algebra

I would like to know if there is a name for the class of commutative (i.e., $\phi(x,y)=\phi(y,x)$) lattice-morphisms $\phi : L_1\times L_{1} \rightarrow L_2$  with the following property:

$\phi(x \sqcap y, x \sqcup y) = \phi(x, y)$.

Note that when $L_{1}$ is linearly ordered, the equality is automatically satisfied.

Are objects of this kind studied somewhere?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by 'commutative' in the question?

Comment: Ittay: i edited the question specifying what I mean by commutative.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that $L_1\times L_1$ is endowed with the lexicographical order?

Comment: No, it's the ordinary product on Lattices: $(a,b)\leq (c,d)$ iff $a\leq c$ AND $b\leq d$

Comment: So if $L_1$ is actually a linear order, these are the functions that are symmetric about the diagonal?

Comment: Brian: yes, indeed

Answer (score 2):

There is a name for these maps. They are called **constant maps**.

To see that the condition

$(\dagger)\; \phi(x,y)=\phi(x\sqcap y,x\sqcup y)$

implies constancy, I investigate what $(\dagger)$ implies about the kernel of $\phi$. Let's write $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if $\phi(a,b)=\phi(c,d)$, i.e. if these pairs are $\ker(\phi)$-related.

$(\dagger)$ implies that 
$\phi(x,y)=\phi(x\sqcap y,x\sqcup y)=\phi(y\sqcap x,y\sqcup x)=\phi(y,x)$, so $(x,y)\sim(y,x)$ for any $x, y\in L_1$. Thus $(\dagger)$ implies $(x,y)=((x,y)\sqcap(x,y))\sim ((x,y)\sqcap (y,x))=(x\sqcap y,x\sqcap y)$, that is $(x,y)\sim(x\sqcap y,x\sqcap y)$, and similarly $(x,y)\sim (x\sqcup y,x\sqcup y)$. In words, this shows that every pair $(x,y)\in L_1\times L_1$ is $\sim$-related to a diagonal element, $(x\sqcap y,x\sqcap y)$, and that any two diagonal elements of the form $(x\sqcap y,x\sqcap y)$ and $(x\sqcup y,x\sqcup y)$ are $\sim$-related to each other.

I want to show that any two diagonal elements are $\sim$-related to each other, thereby showing that $\ker(\phi) = L_1\times L_1$, or equivalently that $\phi$ is constant. So choose any $(c,c), (d,d)$ on the diagonal of $L_1\times L_1$. By earlier arguments, $(c,d)\sim (c\sqcup d,c\sqcup d)\sim (c\sqcap d,c\sqcap d)$. Hence $(c,c) = ((c,c)\sqcap (c\sqcup d, c\sqcup d))\sim ((c,c)\sqcap (c\sqcap d, c\sqcap d))=(c\sqcap d, c\sqcap d)$, so $(c,c)\sim (c\sqcap d,c\sqcap d)$, and similarly $(d,d)\sim (c\sqcap d,c\sqcap d)$, so $(c,c)\sim (d,d)$.